# firebase-auth-client.js replaced by firebase-simple-login.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I've inherited some firebase code that includes

```
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-auth-client.js"></script>
```

But I don't see any references to this library on firebase.com. Has firebase-auth-client.js been deprecated and I should replace the above with :

```
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, if you run the old code with the debugger up, you'll see that it throws a warning stating that firebase-auth-client was replaced with firebase-simple-login. The syntax should be the same so it's as simple as changing the URL.